# How to edit timed logout in Spring security

Tags: java, spring, logout, spring-security

I am trying to figure out where the timed-logout function of Spring's light security is located, and how to edit it to use my custom logout method.
My understanding is that there does exist an editable timed-logout function, I have just thus far been unable to find it, and when/if I do, I am unsure how to make it use my logout sequence.

Thanks,
MirroredFate

EDIT FOR CLARITY:

It is a web/servlet application.  I am using acegi security.

I am using the Spring session timeout right now:

```
In web.xml:
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>5</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

I need a way to execute some code when this timeout occurs.  However, I have NO idea how to do this.

If I am unable to execute code using this method, my understanding is that acegi has a way to make a session timeout; however, I have no idea how to do that either.  I already have the ability to execute the code on a normal logout using acegi:

```
<security:logout invalidate-session="true"
                success-handler-ref="Logout"
                logout-url="/logout.html" />
</security:http>
```

So, essentially, how do I do this same thing either with an acegi timed logout or when a session timeout occurs?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you talking about a Session timer? e.g. a timer that counts down, and when it is finished, ends the user's session?

Comment: Ah, perhaps... that is more or less to what I am referring...  It is my understanding that Spring security comes with this functionality (I really don't know Spring very well), and one can set the amount of time, as well as what to do when the time runs out.  I would like to know specifically how to do this.  Does that clarify at all?

Comment: what type of application? web/servlet? GUI, desktop, etc? Will need a lot more specifics to help you out.

Comment: It's a web/servlet application.  Just tell me what info would be useful and I will give it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `HttpSessionListener` might be what you are looking for.  The problem with depending on Spring's session management is that if a user simply closes his browser without logging out, the invalid-session-url will never be reached (because they never make another request).

Something like this:

```
public class MySessionListner implements HttpSessionListener {
     public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
          return; //or maybe do something, depends on what you need
     }

     public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
          HttpSession session = se.getSession();
          //do whatever you need to do
     }
 }
```

Then in `web.xml`:

```
 <listener>
      <listener-class>com.foo.MySessionListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
```

That way your code will be called every time a session is destroyed, not just when a user tries to access a page after timing out.  Hope that helps.

Comment: This is, I think, what I was looking for.  w00t!  If I hadn't already selected the other dude's answer, I would choose this.

Comment: @MirroredFate I think you can switch the answer to this one. It does answer your question better. (and I found it useful, too)

Answer (score 2):

The session timeout period is managed by your application server (just as you have it now in the `web.xml`). The handling for what happens when the session timeout occurs can be specified in Spring. For instance, Spring 3.0 can specify what page to redirect the user to when they make a request after their session has been invalidated. See below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<b:beans xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

        <sec:http auto-config="true" access-denied-page="/login">
            <sec:session-management invalid-session-url="/session-timeout" />
            <sec:anonymous enabled="true" />
            <sec:intercept-url ... />
            <sec:form-login ... />
            <sec:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/login" />
        </sec:http>
    <!-- Other bean declarations --> 
</b:beans>
```

Comment: Where is this supposed to go in relation to the application?  I mean, does it go in the web.xml, or the application-context, or...*sigh*...  Thanks for the answer, regardless.

Comment: You probably have a file like `${app.name}-servlet.xml`. Sounds like you know how to create a separate context file (i.e. `application-context.xml`). There is documentation on how to separate your security context into a third file. See http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/petclinic-tutorial.html

Comment: ...I was over-complicating this in my mind, I think...
I understand setting the invalid-session-url, but how do I make it use my custom code, as it does for the logout function?  I need to give it a reference to the Logout bean, do you know how to do that? Tyvm.

Comment: If I have answered your original question, please mark as answered. You are asking if there is any way to override or add additional functionality to the stock logout? I am not sure of that since I have not needed to do it myself. I suggest reading the Spring Security 3.0 documentation. You might have to create a logout filter.

Comment: Yes, I am reading the documentation right now. I will mark the question as answered, I suppose, although it isn't really answered.  My question was about how to execute code, and your answer seems to be about how to change the redirection when a timeout occurs.  It is a step in the right direction, and very helpful, so I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: Oh, I see. Take a look at these 2 pages. http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/session-mgmt.html and http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/session/SessionAuthenticationStrategy.html. This should give you the functionality you need to customize how the session authentication is validated (and add to it as you require).